Unable To Import Array From `.txt` File
I have an app in flask but in my main.js file I can't import an array from a .txt file.
It's better to create a file like start.js
let  fs = require("fs")
let readFileLines = filename =>
  fs
    .readFileSync(filename)
    .toString('UTF8')
let arr = readFileLines('File.txt');
console.log(arr)

and prompt the command: node start.js
logs the arr correctly while in my main.js
function myFunction() {
  let fs = require("fs")
  let readFileLines = filename =>
  fs
    .readFileSync(filename)
    .toString('UTF8')
  let arr = readFileLines('File.txt');
  return arr
}


text: myFunction(),

it doesn't return the arr .
I need it to load data into my plotly and if I try to do this test function it goes well
function myFunctionTest() {
  arr = ["1","2"];
  return arr
}


what is the last line in main.js supposed to do exactly? text: myFunction()?

Are you sure you are using the right tool correctly to achieve your goal? I don't see the connection between your code and Flask and I wonder why you expect an array as return.
